# Scripting Language for C++

Tags: javascript, c++, lua

I have an the need to use a scripting language, but I have a horrible list of requirements.
The workstations(PS2 Linux) at uni do not let us have admin access and have a very old version of GCC).

Can anybody recommend a script language that ...

- Work on Linux
- GCC 2.95.2 :(
- No need for admin access
- Easy to integrate with C++
- No need to for additional libraries
- No boost (its just to big for the networked drives at uni, I have complained on numerous occasions, but they feel 1 gig suits *all* students regardless of a computing course or a nursing course.)

The scripts will be doing small amounts of logic for game-objects.

Luabind would be my first choice, but boost makes it impossible, and since the workstations are reset all the time, I would have to reinstall everything :(

Comment: why are you forced to use their machine? you can easily get one that is better

Comment: You could try [SpiderMonkey](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/SpiderMonkey) (JavaScript) perhaps...

Comment: You can dowload/build and install gcc to a local directory (ie not a system directory). You just set your path to the local directory when using gcc

Comment: @Martin That is nice to know, although I would be worried about break compatibly with other bits of software, and I'd have to do it each time the machines are reset. It would be worth it though.

Comment: Any chance of getting GCC patched, and Boost installed by an admin? Keep nagging! IT support *is* busy and under-staffed at Universities but if enough people ask for it (*not* complain – keep polite!) they will eventually react.

Comment: @prusswan I'd have to buy my own PS2 and Linux dev kit. Firstly they are way overpriced on ebay, secondly I'd rather not have to do that. It would also stop me be able to work on it while at uni.

Comment: are you able to install onto a thumbdrive and plug it into that machine?

Comment: @prusswan, I think that would be possible, certainly the usb's are available and you can use a usb keyboard

Comment: PS 2.95 is very old and very broken. It was not until 2.96 that I would even consider it worth using in any real projects.

Comment: @Martin It drives me up the wall. I lobbied for it to be upgraded last year, they are petrified it will break software already written for it.

Comment: @prusswan I dont seem to be able to mount the usb drive, so this is out I guess.

Comment: perhaps ask the lab assistant/admin to assist with mounting the usb drive? they must have a way to do the file transfers

Comment: Why do you NEED to use Luabind? There are so many ways to generate C/Lua bindings (manually, SWIG, tolua++, ...), do you insist on Luabind?

Comment: @Michal Kottman I didn't say I needed Luabind, and I'm certainly not insisting, its just my first choice due to I've used it before. This all comes down to my compiler unfortunately. I think this is a lost cause.

Comment: As far as Lua is concerned, any ANSI C compiler is fine. Lua is also very small and does not depend on any additional libraries. If the amount of objects/methods is not large, the easiest thing to do is manual binding. IMHO nothing is lost, even though the compiler is old :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use Lua, and don't use their machines. If you must, keep your full dev environment and dependencies on a flash drive. Lua is literally the industry standard for this.

Comment: yes i would recommend lua, we have been using it with greath sucess.

Comment: @禪 師 無 I'd rather not have to buy my own PS2 and Linux Dev kit. @Naresh Lua would be my first preference.

Comment: You can also give LuaJIT a spin too, even if you don't use the JIT for what ever reason, the VM is still pretty powerful

Comment: I've ended writing my own Lua glue code, as I cant get any of the libraries working on such an old spec.

Answer (score 4):

I want to recommend Angelscript:

http://www.angelcode.com/angelscript/

It is damn easy to integrate with C++ and has threading and all. 
Sample integration:

```
r = engine->RegisterGlobalFunction("void print(const string &in)", asFUNCTION(print), asCALL_CDECL); assert( r >= 0 );
```

You cannot have it more easy. Classes have the same syntax but asMETHOD instead of asFUNCTION. It also supports exporting classes, having factories and comes with some premades like string and math. 
The language itself is a mix of C++, Java and Python, but really good.

Try it, I fell in love with it once I understood how to use it.

No scripting language I tried was so easy to integrate like Angelscript. And I tried quite a lot, like Python, LUA, Javascript etc.

edit: Some Code from my program, shows the integration of a class for you:

```
// Registering the interface to angelscript
void NLBoundingBox::registerWithAngelScript( asIScriptEngine* e )
{    
    AS_ERR_CHECK(e->RegisterObjectType("NLBoundingBox", 0, asOBJ_REF));
    AS_ERR_CHECK(e->RegisterObjectMethod("NLBoundingBox", "bool intersects(const NLBoundingBox@)", asMETHOD(NLBoundingBox, intersects), asCALL_THISCALL));
    AS_ERR_CHECK(e->RegisterObjectMethod("NLBoundingBox", "bool isPointInside(f32 x, f32 y)", asMETHODPR(NLBoundingBox, isPointInside, (f32,f32), bool), asCALL_THISCALL));
    AS_ERR_CHECK(e->RegisterObjectMethod("NLBoundingBox", "void translate(f32 x, f32 y)", asMETHODPR(NLBoundingBox, translate, (f32,f32), void), asCALL_THISCALL));
    AS_ERR_CHECK(e->RegisterObjectMethod("NLBoundingBox", "void translateTo(f32 x, f32 y)", asMETHODPR(NLBoundingBox, translateTo, (f32,f32), void), asCALL_THISCALL));
    AS_ERR_CHECK(e->RegisterObjectMethod("NLBoundingBox", "void rotateAroundCenter(f32 angle)", asMETHOD(NLBoundingBox, rotateAroundCenter), asCALL_THISCALL));

    // Behaviour: Factory and Refs
    AS_ERR_CHECK(e->RegisterObjectBehaviour("NLBoundingBox", asBEHAVE_FACTORY, "NLBoundingBox@ NLBoundingBox()", asFUNCTIONPR(factory, (void), NLBoundingBox*), asCALL_STDCALL));
    AS_ERR_CHECK(e->RegisterObjectBehaviour("NLBoundingBox", asBEHAVE_RELEASE, "void NLBoundingBox()", asMETHOD(NLBoundingBox, release), asCALL_THISCALL));
    AS_ERR_CHECK(e->RegisterObjectBehaviour("NLBoundingBox", asBEHAVE_ADDREF, "void NLBoundingBox()", asMETHOD(NLBoundingBox, addRef), asCALL_THISCALL));
}
```

Comment: Lua is _not_ an acronym; it should not be in all caps. Sorry; personal pet peeve. Also, you may want to point out that the Angelscript language is statically typed, so it loses some of the advantages of most scripting languages.

Comment: I shall also add that it is intrusive.